# Snowflake Lateral Flatten Key is not working

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I'm using the following query in snowflake:

```
SELECT nested_flattened_items.name
FROM HEVO.SHIPSTATION.SHIPSTATION_ORDERS,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => HEVO.SHIPSTATION.SHIPSTATION_ORDERS.ITEMS) flattened_items,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => flattened_items.value) nested_flattened_items
```

However, when I run it, it says: Error: invalid identifier 'NESTED_FLATTENED_ITEMS.NAME' (line 36)

Whenever I run a query to check if the key exists, it runs and I blatantly notice the key "name."

```
SELECT nested_flattened_items.*
FROM HEVO.SHIPSTATION.SHIPSTATION_ORDERS,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => HEVO.SHIPSTATION.SHIPSTATION_ORDERS.ITEMS) flattened_items,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => flattened_items.value) nested_flattened_items
```

Any idea how to resolve?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPpv1.png)

Comment: try replacing the  'name' with 'value' e.g. remove this =>nested_flattened_items.name add this=> nested_flattened_items.value